# Recommendations to host an intranet page (local web server page) inside Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, intranet

I have been tasked with selecting and implementing org chart publishing software for my company.  Our strategy is (wherever possible) to host apps, services and content on the could, and exploit our O365 to the fullest extent possible. Unfortunately, I'm not all that impressed with the org chart apps that run native on SP Online.

I'm considering buying some software that will run on one of our local web servers, and embedding the page into a SharePoint-based intranet. (i.e. users will access SharePoint Online, and not even be aware the content is coming from the local server)

Has anyone had any success/failure with such such a setup? Any advice or recommendations?  Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstood it but using external DLLs are not allowed in SharePoint Online. Kindly check here.... http://o365fxcoprules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Supported%20Rules&version=1

Comment: If you want to use external datasource only thank kindly check this...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101704/does-sharepoint-online-support-external-data-sources

Comment: Yes, possible, as long as users have access to your local webserver.